# Simulating a microphone with a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, microphone

I'm trying to use a microcontroller to replace where a microphone would normally be connected (to a radio module) to feed a sine wave into the radio module.  I can produce a sine wave (I think) but it will be between 0-3.3v.  How can I make it acceptable as what a microphone would be?  I'm guessing I need a series capacitor to block the DC component, but is that enough?  And if so, how do I choose the right capacitor for this use case?

(The radio module is a DRA818V and the MCU is an STM32L0, if that helps any.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest an attenuator and a DC block.  Microphone outputs are nowhere near 3.3 volts, so you will probably need to divide that down 100x to 1000x with a voltage divider.  A DC blocking cap forms a high pass filter, so just figure out what the source and load impedances are, calculate the cutoff frequency (f = 1/RC) and figure out what cap value will give you a cutoff lower than the lowest frequency you're interested in.  Generally something in the ballpark of 1 to 100 uF should work.

Comment: Hrrm, ok, so is the "R" in the high-pass filter the entire attenuator, or what contributes to that R?  (FWIW, the datasheet for the radio device does not give an impedance value for the microphone pin.)

Comment: If you use a standard voltage divider add the attenuator, then the R well be the parallel combination of the two resistor values.